# Checking if a set in the game Set is valid: How to Refactor code

Tags: swift, swiftui, switch-statement

I'm trying to build Set on SwiftUI and want to see if I have a valid set. For those not familiar with the game, I need to check if every card shares the same feature or every card has different features: for example, card1 has blue color, card2 has blue color, and card3 has blue color works, as does card1 has blue color, card2 has red color, and card3 has green color - they must all be the same or all different. I need to check that this holds for shapes, colors, quantity, and filling. I wrote the code to check the color below. As I was writing the code for the other features, I realized it's literally the same as my colorsAreValid function

```
    private func colorsAreValid(for cards: [Card]) -> Bool {
        var red = 0
        var green = 0
        var blue = 0
        for index in cards.indices {
            switch cards[index].color {
                case Color.red:
                    red += 1
                case Color.green:
                    green += 1
                case Color.purple:
                    blue += 1
            }
        }
        return red == 1 && green == 1 && blue == 1 || red == 3 || green == 3 || blue == 3
    }
```

I can rename red as item1, green as item2, blue as item3, but my trouble then is trying to pass an argument such that if I pass in "Color", I switch on cards[index].color; if I pass in "Shape", I switch on cards[index].shape. How do I do this? Same holds with the cases themselves.

Here is more code to show my set-up

```
    private static var colors = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.purple]
    
    private static var shapes = [Shape.rectangle, Shape.oval, Shape.diamond]
    
    private static var fillings = [Filling.empty, Filling.full, Filling.squiggly]
    
    private static var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
    
    enum Color {
        case red
        case green
        case purple
    }
    
    enum Shape {
        case rectangle
        case oval
        case diamond
    }
    
    enum Filling {
        case empty
        case full
        case squiggly
    }
    
    struct Card: Identifiable {
        var color: Color
        var shape: Shape
        var filling: Filling
        var number: Int
        var id: Int
        var isSelected = false
    }
```

Comment: You can generalize this function by naming it something like `featuresFormASet` or something like that, and passing in a KeyPath which decides which feature to look at

Comment: You can tighten up your logic by using, amusingly, the `Set` type. Create a `Set<Color>` from the card colors. If the color set's `count` is 1 or 3, it's a valid color set. Thus:`private func colorsAreValid(for cards: [Card]) -> Bool { let count = cards.reduce(into: Set<Color>()) { $0.insert($1.color) }.count; return count == 1 || count == 3 }`

Comment: You can then make it generic over the feature: `private func feature<F: Hashable>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Card, F>, isValidFor cards: [Card]) -> Bool { let count = cards.reduce(into: Set<F>()) { $0.insert($1[keyPath: keyPath]) }.count; return count == 1 || count == 3}`. Usage: `feature(\.color, isValidFor: cards) || feature(\.shape, isValidFor: cards) || feature(\.filling, isValidFor: cards) || feature(\.number, isValidFor: cards)`